# React Native - should I relink after an library update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After I update an already existing React Native library, is it necessary to relink it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linking just sets up your native projects to link to the module in your `node_modules`. Unless there is a major change to the module, you only need to do it once.

For iOS, this will modify your `.pbxproj` file, updating your targets and adding links to the framework (if needed) and the `.xcodeproj` in `node_modules/<module>`

For android, it will modify your `settings.gradle` file to include the project from `node_modules`. It will also update your `build.gradle` to compile the new library, and it will modify your `MainApplication.java` file to add the new lib to react.

Comment: How do I know if it's a major change?

Comment: I put that more as a caveat for myself. A major change that required a relink would be in the release notes of the module but would be highly unlikely unless there was a change to a core library that was used or something like that.

Comment: I also have the same question. Ex. I just updated the react-native-webview from v2 to v3 and without linking the IOS part again, I got the **linker command failed with exit code 1** error. I manually relinked it by adding the RNWebview.xcproj from node_modules and adding RBWebview.a in the "link binaries with lis" section of build_phase. That solved the error. Can RN not just pick up the new file form the same location?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to relink the lib.

Comment: So iOS project just uses a link to the node_modules right?